# Android: how to specify 2 styles for EditText?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-styles

I work on a **Xamarin Android app**, and I create a **SearchBar** that looks like on iOS.

For this, I use an `EditText` but I need to apply 2 different styles for the **placeholder** and the **entered text**:

- **placeholder**: FontFamily A, TextSize A, TextColor A, ...
- **entered text** : FontFamily B, TextSize B, TextColor B, ...

I know that I can specify the color, but I don't see how to redefine other properties (FontFamily, TextSize, ...)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchbar_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/searchbar_spacing"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/searchbar_search_image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="Search for a place or address"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    style="@style/MontserratRegular13Grey"/>
```

***How could I achieve this?***

Comment: 2 different xmls, I don't think you can change style to a view programtically

Answer (score 0):

You can specify 2 styles for editext and the hint by using string resource for hint:

```
android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
```

and setting the hint style in string.xml in your values resource.

I created a simple sample and it works:

layout.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchbar_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/edittext_hint" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App45</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edittext_hint">
      <font size="50" color="blue">Hint here!</font>
    </string>
</resources>
```

BTW, the strings.xml is in the values folder in the resource.

Comment: I've tried but this doesn't work as expected.
If I doesn't set the text of the `hint` through the code, the style is well applied.
But when I set the text through the code; the style is no longer applied. And I need to set the text through the code, as the app is multilingual...